# How to disable button inside kendo grid cell based on some condition?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I am having 1 column in my grid with name **status** and my last column of grid contains Column that is **Action**.

In this **Action column** i have two button that is **Edit and Delete**.

Now when my **Status value is pending** i want to make my **delete button disable with tooltip**:**Cant delete record with status except pending**.

This is my code:

```
                    {
                        field: "Status",
                        title: "Status",
                        width: 200,
                        template: '#if(Status) {#Approved#} else{#Pending#}#'
                    },
                    {
                       field: "Id",
                       title: "Action",
                       width: 60,
                       template: "<a title='Edit' href=''></a><a onclick='javascript:return Delete(\"#:Id#\",\"grid2\");' title='delete'><img src='@Url.Content("~/img/delete.png")' /></a> //Disable this delete when status is except pending.
                       sortable: false
                   }
```

How to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. We can not disable the anchor tag so I have removed onclick event from anchor tag, where its status is pending.

```
columns: [{
    field: "Status",
    title: "Status"
},
{
    field: "StudentID",
    title: "Action",
    template: "<a title='Edit' href=''>Edit</a> " +
                "#if(Status=='Approved'){#   <a onclick='javascript:return Delete(\"#:StudentID#\",\"grid2\");' title='delete'>Delete</a> #}#" +
                "#if(Status=='Pending'){#   <a title='Cant delete record with status except pending'>Delete</a> #}#"


}]
```

Sample data:

[image]

Comment: just wanted to ask you 1 question that i have put image button for edit and delete in between anchor tag so when hovering on edit tag my pointer turns in to hand shape but not in case of delete button.you have any idear about this?

Comment: In our case for edit button kendo will apply CSS automatically and for delete we have to manually apply style property for same. For more detail please check below link.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor

In-addition I have also updated my above answer for same.

Comment: But why this behaviour as such both edit and delete are just image button so if i am getting pointer on edit button then y not on delete button?

Comment: I have looked into this and found that not any kendo-CSS property applied  to any (Edit/Delete) anchor tag. It shows pointer cursor only in edit button because we have added 'href' attribute in the button.

Comment: ok so because of href attribute in edit button it is showing pointer.Got your point.Thanks

Comment: bro can you please help me with this question.i am badly stuck in this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218159/not-able-to-check-and-uncheck-the-checkboxes-inside-the-radcombox